# How to create fragemented file with mp4box.js

Tags: javascript, mp4box

I know that you can do this to create a dash file:

```
MP4Box -dash 10000 -frag 1000 -rap -single-segment test.mp4
```

But what would the equivalent (giving a filename, and converting it to a dash file) be in javascript where I link mp4box.js via cdn?

I've tried looking at the docs, and I'll continue looking at them, but I know for sure they did not show how to use mp4box with js in the most efficient way and it just has me stumped.

I'm looking at this here because it seems like this is part of what I have to use, but it isn't even containing everything it needs for it to work:

```
var mp4box = MP4Box.createFile();
mp4boxfile.onReady = function(info) {
  ...
  mp4boxfile.onSegment = function (id, user, buffer) {}
  mp4boxfile.setSegmentOptions(info.tracks[0].id, sb, options);  
  var initSegs = mp4boxfile.initializeSegmentation();  
  mp4boxfile.start();
  ...
};
```

The docs - > https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js/

If anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Comment: `but it isn't even containing everything it needs for it to work:` you need to fill in the blanks (sb and options for a start) and code as required by YOU - the author of that library doesn't know what you want to do :p

Comment: I shall take a closer look. Also what does sb mean? I don't see it much in the library, does it stand for something? Lastly, I don't understand with the code I'm given how to capture the resulting dash file I want to create. I'm going to head off to bed now so I will not respond for quite some time.

Comment: it seems to be referred to as `user` elsewhere